# How to get the "Reported device Ids hash" property of my USB dongle in Powershell

Tags: usb, powershell

I need to get the `Reported device Ids hash` property of my USB dongle with Powershell. Is this possible and if so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I need to get the `Reported device Ids hash` property of my USB dongle

This is possible if your device is running a supported version of Windows 10 semi-annual channel.

> The hardware hash for an existing device is available through Windows
> Management Instrumentation (WMI), as long as that device is running a
> supported version of Windows 10 semi-annual channel. You can use a
> PowerShell script ([Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo)) to get a
> device's hardware hash and serial number. The serial number is useful
> to quickly see which device the hardware hash belongs to.
>
> To use this script, you can use either of the following methods:
>
> - Download the script file from the PowerShell Gallery and run it on each computer.
> - Install the script directly from the PowerShell Gallery.
>
> To install it directly and capture the hardware hash from the local
> computer, use the following commands from an elevated Windows
> PowerShell prompt: PowerShell
>
> ```
> New-Item -Type Directory -Path "C:\HWID"
> Set-Location -Path "C:\HWID"
> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
> Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo
> Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1 -OutputFile AutoPilotHWID.csv
> ```

Source: [Manually register devices with Windows Autopilot | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/autopilot/add-devices)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This works. The script returns a `Hardware Hash`. Just what I needed, though it seems it's different then `Reported device Ids hash` under device properties. (It's a lot longer). I'm happy with this answer as I needed to get an unique ID, though idk what the difference is betweeen the two.

Comment: You can change the title if you want to be more specific.